# Examples of Projectivization of Vector Bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I was going through vector bundles from Hatcher's where he defines associated fiber bundles i.e Projective bundle but he doesn't give any examples related to that.

Can anyone suggest some examples of calculating the projective bundle from some common examples (apart from trivial bundle) for e.g Canonical bundle, Tangent bundle over say Projective space etc?

thanks and regards

Comment: I do not know alternative descriptions of the projectivizations in the examples you ask about, but here's a different example you might find interesting: if you take the tautological (complex) line bundle $H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ (the one where the fiber over a point is the line spanned by it, not the dual), its (real) projectivization is the sphere bundle of its tensor square $H^{\otimes2}$ (noting $S^1\cong\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$) and its total space is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2n+1}$.

Comment: That does sound interesting, any material related to that could be helpful can you suggest something? Also Can we expect something similar if your Tautological bundle is over a Real Projective space @Thorgott

Comment: I do not know any material, though this is no doubt well-known. The comment section is a bit too narrow to explain this, but you can find me in the MSE chatroom if you want me to elaborate. As for the tautological bundle over real projective space, it is a real line bundle. The real projectivization of a real line bundle is a bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^0$, i.e. a point, so simply homeomorphic to the base.

Comment: In fact that could even be true for any line bundle, right?

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana - If $C:=\mathbb{P}^1$ is the projective line and $E:=\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(d)$ with $\mathcal{O}(d)$ the line bundle of degree $d$, it follows $F(d):=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(d))$  is the Hirzebruch surface. There is a fibration $\pi: F(d) \rightarrow C$ and $\pi$ is Zariski locally trivial with fiber the projective line.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch_surface